# Using special characters or email addresses as SQL login

Tags: sql-server

I was troubleshooting a SQL Server 2008 R2 today and the server was generating a ton of connection errors from multiple services. In looking at how the server had been setup the user had a number of services set to run under specific login credentials. The client had setup within the configuration manager the SQL Server default instance to run under the account `someusername@somedomain.org` with a set password

I saw this used in a number of locations including the SQL Server Analysis Service SQL Server Agent as well as within the IIS app pools and other windows services that communicate with SQL Server. Looking at the SQL console logs the server was churning out failed login errors on the minute.

In the past I have always setup these service accounts using either Network Service (for intranet deployments) or a domain account `somedomain\somename` that is provisioned to work as a service account. The email address which was being used was not provisioned as a SQL Server login but there was a domain user account `domain\someusername` added as a SQL Server login on the server. To me these are not the same in SQL Server, `domain\someusername != someusername@somedomain.org` is that incorrect to assume?

I am in the process of setting everything to a baseline by resetting all the services to use `NetworkService` so I can at least get everything working properly.

My question is, are there restrictions on using special characters in login's for SQL Server? I had always thought that you did not want( or could not ) use special characters for creating logins such as an email addresses. I know when registering an IIS machine against SQL you can use the machine name as `domain\machinename$`. It seems to me that an email address is not a valid domain account as it could be an alias etc and that you would want to explicitly use a valid domain user/service account.

Can anyone provide me some reference material on what is allowed? When I search msdn or google I get more results on SQL injections or escaping passwords. I just want to have a more solid understanding of what is allowed as it pertains to a SQL Server login, as well as what a documented best practice is moving forward so when explaining what to do or what not to do I have some legit reference.

The client has the server set to use mixed mode authentication but it looks as if they are trying to set everything up to rely on windows authentication for connectivity to the server.

thanks for any insight,

-cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Account Objects have two names - a User Principal Name and a SAMID - both of which must be unique in the Forest. These can be seen in the Account tab in Active Directory Users and Computers.

The User Principal Name consist of the logon name followed by a UPN Suffix. For example, `andrea@adventure-works.com`. UPN Suffixes are properties of the Forest and are unrelated to email domains (though for sanity's sake, they should match email addresses :-).

The SAMID consists of the NetBIOS name of the Active Directory domain followed by the logon name (pre-Windows 2000). For example `ADVENTURE-WORKS\andrea`.

Most software accepts both types of name but a few accept only one or the other.